# WPF DataGrid begin editing on Double Click not Single Click

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a WPF DataGrid with Text columns that are editable.
I also am able to drag-drop them and place them in a different view.

Unfortunately, if the row already has selection and I try to drag it, it enters edition mode instead... 
I rather enter edition mode on double click, so that a single click on the row can be used as a start drag.

Currently, the work around is to never select the row before dragging it

I saw a couple of similar questions, but none actually addressing this problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
// Theres a million ways I'd rather do that
public class DoubleClickEditDataGrid : DataGrid
{
    protected override void OnCanExecuteBeginEdit(CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Parameter is MouseButtonEventArgs)
        {
            if ((e.Parameter as MouseButtonEventArgs).ClickCount <= 1)
            {
                e.CanExecute = false;
                return;
            }
        }
        base.OnCanExecuteBeginEdit(e);
    }
}
```